# How single external ip can route to mutiple servers behind the router?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan, port-forwarding

Lets not talk on the of scale of big data center. Keep it simple. Every users gets an internet connection from an ISP. And if i want to run a web server. I usually forward the packets from my router to the desired computer. This is called as port forwarding.

Lets take for instance, I have two servers in my lan. I want both the servers to be actively responding. I have a single external ip say 182.22.XXX.XXX.
I can only port forward to one computer. How can i port forward the same port 80 to two computers in the lan. can how does the person outside the lan differentiate the computers that is inside the lan. since we have only one external ip in our case??

Comment: Look up NAT and PAT for router configuration techniques depending how robust yours is.  See similar answers posted her as well that seems specific without me reading through it all.   http://superuser.com/questions/506390/one-external-ip-2-servers

Comment: In a data center, every server has a unique public IP and is not sitting behind a NAT, so its actually a simpler setup.  But, in your situation I would setup a lightweight reverse proxy that handles virtual hosts that proxy to your individual servers.

Comment: simply put, you cannot do what you describe without having one of them on an alternate port, or getting more than one IP from the ISP and a router capable of running multiple WAN IPs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can i port forward the same port 80 to two computers in the lan. can how does the person outside the lan differentiate the computers that is inside the lan. since we have only one external ip in our case??

The simple answer is **"you cannot"**.

The HTTP-specific answer is "forward all connections to a reverse proxy that uses the HTTP 'Host' header" (e.g. nginx); similarly, for TLS (HTTPS) connections, a reverse proxy could distinguish based on TLS SNI extension (e.g. haproxy).

Comment: Now the answer makes more sense. Thanks for helping me to learn.